# Why is this a differentiable structure on the product manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, products

Suppose $M$ en $N$ are differentiable manifolds with differentiable structures $\{(U_a,x_a)\}$ and $\{(V_b,x_b)\}$ resp. Consider $M\times N$ and the mappings $z_{ab}(p,q):=(x_a(p),y_b(q))$ with $p\in U_a$ and $q\in V_b$.

I want to prove that $\{(U_a\times V_b,z_{ab})\}$ gives a differentiable structure on $M\times N$ such that the projections $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are differentiable.

Is this good?!:
$$\bigcup_{ab}{z_{ab}(U_a\times V_b)}=\bigcup_a{x_a(U_a)}\times\bigcup_b{y_b(V_b)}=M\times N$$
My problem lies in the second point of the definition of a differentiable manifold: Suppose $z_{ab}(U_a\times V_b)\cap z_{cd}(U_c\times V_d)=W\neq\emptyset$
Why are $z^{-1}_{ab}(W)$ and $z^{-1}_{cd}(W)$ open?

I think $z^{-1}_{cd}\circ z_{ab}$ is differentiable because:
$$z^{-1}_{cd}\circ z_{ab}(p,q)=z^{-1}_{cd}(z_{ab}(p,q))=((x^{-1}_c\circ x_a)(p),(y^{-1}_d\circ y_b)(q)$$ and this is differentiable per assumption in each component thus differentiable.

But why are the projections differentiable? Herefore we have to prove that $y^{-1}_b\circ\pi\circ x_a$ are differentiable for all $a$ and $b$ right?! But how to do this?

Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 3):

Your definition of the differentiable structure is fine. (EDIT: Let me expand that a bit, I haven't recognised your first question the first time.)
Indeed, since the families of open sets $\{x_a(U_a)\}_a$ cover $M$ and $\{y_b(V_b)\}_b$ covers $N$, their pairwise products form an open covering of $M\times N$. Even though it's true in that case (because we take all possible combinations), I wouldn't simply write $$\bigcup_{a,b}z_{a,b}(U_a\times V_b) = \bigcup_a x_a(U_a)\times\bigcup_b y_b(V_b).$$ It's $\bigcup_{a,b}z_{a,b}(U_a\times V_b) = \bigcup_{a,b}x_a(U_a)\times y_b(V_b)$, thus the only trivial inclusion is $$\bigcup_{a,b}z_{a,b}(U_a\times V_b)\subset \bigcup_a x_a(U_a)\times\bigcup_b y_b(V_b)=M\times N.$$ To see equality, given any point $(p,q)\in M\times N$, there exist indices $a,b$, such that $p\in x_a(U_a)$ and $q\in y_b(V_b)$. Hence, $(p,q)\in x_a(U_a)\times y_b(V_b)\subset\bigcup_{a,b}z_{a,b}(U_a\times V_b)$.

Now, given $U_a$, $V_b$, $U_c$ and $V_d$, $$W=z_{a,b}(U_a\times V_b)\cap z_{c,d}(U_c\times V_d) = (x_a(U_a)\times y_b(V_b))\cap(x_c(U_c)\times y_d(V_d))$$
is an intersection of (products of) open sets, hence an open subset of $M\times N$. The maps $x_a$ and $y_b$ are continuous, and therefore so is their product $z_{a,b}$. Consequently, $z_{a,b}^{-1}(W)$ is an open subset of $x_a(U_a)\times y_b(V_b)$.

The expression $y_b^{-1}\circ\pi\circ x_a$ isn't well defined. ($x_a$ maps to $M$, so there is no $\pi$ to apply.)
To verify differentiability of the projections, the maps $x_{a'}^{-1}\circ\pi_1\circ z_{a,b}$ and $x_{b'}^{-1}\circ\pi_2\circ z_{a,b}$ (where ever sensible) have to be proven to be differentiable.

Comment: How can we prove that $x_{a'}^{-1} \circ \pi_1 \circ z_{a, b}$ is differentiable? Is it because $x_{a'}^{-1} \circ \pi_1 \circ z_{a, b}(p, q) = x_{a'}^{-1} \circ \pi_1 \circ x_a (p)$?

Comment: $x_{a'}^{-1}\circ\pi_1\circ z_{a,b}(p,q)= x_{a'}^{-1}\circ x_a(p)$, so it follows from the assumption that we are starting with a smooth atlas.

Comment: I was giving a second thought about this, and I don't know if I agree with you. I agree that given $(p, q) \in U_a \times V_b$, then you wrote an equality of points. But does this work as an equality of functions so that we can assert the differentiability of the right hand side? Shoudn't the domains be the same?

Comment: Dear @DaniloGregorin, yes, I realised after posting that the argument in the comment was incomplete, but I was just hoping you could complete it by yourself. Have you tried to fix it?

Comment: Indeed I tried, by to no end. I am very confused :/

Comment: Okay, let's see.. Let $\mathrm{pr}_1$ be the projection $U_a\times V_b\to U_a$. This map is smooth. Moreover, for all $(p,q)\in U_a\times V_b$ we have $x^{-1}_{a'}\circ\pi_1\circ z_{a,b}(p,q)=x^{-1}_{a'}\circ x_a(p) =p$. I. e., $x^{-1}_{a'}\circ\pi_1\circ z_{a,b}=\mathrm{pr}_1$ is smooth, as claimed.

Comment: I see now. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just a few remarks: Don't we need $a' = a$ to say that the second equality holds true? This is not a big issue, because the solution works if we just take $a' = a$

Comment: Yeah, there went something wrong with the index. The point is that $x_{a'}^{-1}\circ x_a\circ\mathrm{pr}_1$ is smooth, but you have to track the images and pre-images etc. Probably the equality holds on $x_a^{-1}(x_{a'}(U_{a'})\times U_b$ or something like that..

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your help